# Object ambiguity in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, charts

I have some javascript that is loaded multiple times in a page.

```
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
...more with chart object...
        $( "#chartdiv${divId}" ).closest('#mainBox').find('#toggleTrendline').on('click',
                     function() {
                if(chart.trendLines==""){
                    chart.addTrendLine(trendLine)
                    }else{
                    chart.removeTrendLine(trendLine)
                        }
                chart.validateNow()
              });
```

In the above code it have access to `chart` object because this code is in same script that uses chart object.
But this script is loaded multiple times because of multiple charts on same page and all chart's script will have chart object.
Now my question:
Whenever the event in code above happens it don't know what `chart` object to process `addTrendLine` so it calls `addTrendLine/removeTrendLine` on random chart object.
Make sense?

How can i manage things such that every event handler will be handling event on related chart `object` only.
Anybody can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: that was mistaken, thanks for your time TJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever the event in code above happens it don't know what chart object to process `addTrendLine` so it calls `addTrendLine`/`removeTrendLine` on random `chart` object.
>   Make sense?

No, it doesn't. Assuming this code is being loaded as shown (not within another function), the event will always use the *last* `chart` object loaded, because `chart` is a global variable overwritten each time the code is loaded.

> How can i manage things such that every event handler will be handling event on related chart object only.

By putting that code in a scoping function and having the handlers close over their own copy of `chart`:

```
(function () {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    //...more with chart object...
    $("#chartdiv${divId}")
        .closest('#mainBox')
        .find('#toggleTrendline')
        .on('click',
            function () {
                if (chart.trendLines == "") {
                    chart.addTrendLine(trendLine)
                } else {
                    chart.removeTrendLine(trendLine)
                }
                chart.validateNow()
            }
        );
})();
```

Now, `chart` is a *local variable* within the scoping function that the event handlers close over. Each of these units is self-contained.

Of course, I will just point out that you're using elements with `id`s (like `#mainBox`), and `id`s **must** be unique on the page, so there will be interaction between the multiple loads of the code. There's probably a better way to structure this, but the above will at least do what you asked, give you a separate `chart` for each time you repeat the code.

Comment: it works, thanks for the solution Seniore! god bless you